# C++ Advanced Macro

Tags: c++, macros

I would need a macro that simplifies this:

```cpp
foo::bar::getInstance().registerProcess([&]() {
    std::cout << "PROCESS" << std::endl;
},{&a,&b});
```

to something like this:

```
registerProcess {
    std::cout << "PROCESS" << std::endl;
} sensitive {a,b}
```

is something like this even possible?

The second vector parameter could be also empty `{}` or could have more values `{a,b,c,...}`

The closest I could achieve was:

```cpp
#define atomicProcess(a, ...) des::kernel::getInstance().registerProcess([&]()a, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#define suspendableProcess(a, ...) des::kernel::getInstance().registerProcess([&]() -> coroutine a, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#define sensitive ,

    atomicProcess({
        ...;
    } sensitive { &a });

    suspendableProcess({
        ...;
    });
```

if somebody has an idea how to get rid of the `();` would be nice :-)

Comment: What's the signature of `registerProcess()`? Does it accept a variable number of arguments?

Comment: Yeah its variable, it accepts the lambda and optional the vector parameter:

```void registerProcess(std::function<void()> function, std::vector<interface*> sensitivity = {});```

Comment: You want a macro which takes the first block as parameter(s) and outputs the second block? How is the second block valid C++?

Comment: @chtz i don't get your question? this is a vector of references: {&a,&b}

Comment: By "block" I meant the first and second ```-block. But trying to interprete your answer, you actually want to "generate" the first code block using a macro similar to the second code block?

Comment: Exactly that's what I want.

Comment: What compiler(s) are you supporting?  (Asking due to use of `,##__VA_ARGS__`, MSVS weirdness, emptiness case, etc).